# Iterate over 4 random response from an each statement

Tags: javascript, each

I have some data in a JSON file and there are about 20 entries. What I would like to do is display 4 of those entries, at random, each time the page loads.

```js
var data = [
  {'name': 'Bill'},
  {'name': 'Sally'},
  {'name': 'George'},
  {'name': 'Steve'},
  {'name': 'Jill'},
  {'name': 'Jeff'}
];

$.each(data, function(i) {
  var name = data[i].name;
  // Select 4 at random
  $('.results').append('<div>' + name + '</div>');
  
  if(i === 3) {  
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results"></div>
```

I was able to make it so that it only displays 4 with my conditional statement, but how could I modify this so that it selects a random 4 rather than the first 4?

Comment: 1. Shuffle an array https://stackoverflow.com/q/2450954/251311 2. Pick first 4 (using `Array.prototype.slice`)

Comment: You really [don't need jQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif) just to randomly select some values from an array...

Comment: A fairly easy way to do this is to shuffle the array elements, and select the first 4 from there. Here is a related topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: I suggest starting by selecting **one** random element from the array.

Comment: Please find the below response -
 

    var data = [
      {'name': 'Bill'},
      {'name': 'Sally'},
      {'name': 'George'},
      {'name': 'Steve'},
      {'name': 'Jill'},
      {'name': 'Jeff'}
    ];
    var totalData = data.length;
    $.each(data, function(i) {
      
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(totalData));
      var name = data[random].name;
      $('.results').append('<div>' + name + '</div>');
      
      data.splice(random,1);
    
      totalData = totalData - 1;
     if(i === 3){
         return false;
     }
    });

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of cod.

```
    var rndList=[];
    var len=data.length
      while(rndList.length<4){
      var rnd=Math.floor((Math.random() * (len-1)) + 0);
       if(rndList.indexOf(rnd)==-1)
       {
        rndList.push(rnd)
       }
      }

    $.each(rndList, function(i) {
    var idx=rndList[i];
    var name = data[idx].name;

      $('.results').append('<div>' + name + '</div>');

    });
```

Comment: What happens if you select the same `rnd` twice?

Comment: i modified my answer.

Comment: What if `data.length` is 3? What if `Math.random()` returns the same value forever?

Comment: appended items are based on rndList that will never have a duplicate number,because i checked for duplicated number in this code rndList.indexOf(rnd)==-1

Comment: Sure, but what if the original array is of length 3? Or if `Math.random()` returns the same value?

Comment: while loop continues till rndList get filled with unique numbers

Comment: What if the length of the original array is 3? `const data = [1,2,3];` and run your code.

Comment: Also this implementation will never choose `rnd = len - 1`

Comment: you told before '// Select 4 at random' if you want this code be more flexible check it before while loop by a variable based on your list'length.

Comment: It's not about being flexible, but robust. PS: it was not me who asked a question, I just pointed out your code needs extra considerations.